# Is there way to apply EQ effects in HTML 5 web audio API?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I would like to know is there way we can apply EQ effects to audio in html 5 web audio.
I wish to use 2 effects EQ Male and EQ female. I did some reasearch and found that these are nothing but some preset frequencies.

Edit:

Here is what I am looking for.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course.  Web Audio has lots of filtering capabilities.  I did a standard low/mid/high EQ in my wubwubwub app, starting around line 189 of [tracks.js](https://github.com/cwilso/wubwubwub/blob/MixTrack/js/tracks.js) (You may not want "this.", of course):

```
    this.low = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
    this.low.type = "lowshelf";
    this.low.frequency.value = 320.0;
    this.low.gain.value = 0.0;
    this.low.connect( /* your output node here - audioCtx.destination, maybe? */ );

    this.mid = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
    this.mid.type = "peaking";
    this.mid.frequency.value = 1000.0;
    this.mid.Q.value = 0.5;
    this.mid.gain.value = 0.0;
    this.mid.connect( this.low );

    this.high = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
    this.high.type = "highshelf";
    this.high.frequency.value = 3200.0;
    this.high.gain.value = 0.0;
    this.high.connect( this.mid );

    /* Now connect your input to this.high */
```

Comment: Thanks @cwilso. I'm bit confused.I wish to use Male/Female EQ and what you have suggested seems to be different. Basically there is requirement from client and I am not really expert in sound engineering. I might be asking too much but it would be great if you can help me guiding on way to proceed on implementation, even pointers would do. I have added screenshot of what we need to implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing the "EQ male"/"EQ female" is just the request to do a preset EQ curve for males and females (males, obviously, are typically lower pitched).  Just change the frequencies above (e.g. set the this.mid.frequency.value to your desired peak frequency for male/female).  You typically want to tune the EQ, though, not just turn it on and off.